# Datatype mismatch error in ssis

Tags: ssis

I am retrieving some columns from some tables(below two are responsible for errors)

```
CUSTOMER_ID - numeric(9)
INCIDENT_ID - int(4)
```

and moving the results to `foreach loop container`(used derived transformation before moving results into record set i.e., CUSTOMER_ID - DT_NUMERIC,INCIDENT_ID  - DT_I4) but i end up with these two errors

```
ForEach Variable Mapping number 3 to variable "User::CUSTOMER_ID" cannot be applied.
ForEach Variable Mapping number 6 to variable "User::INCIDENT_ID" cannot be applied.
The type of the value being assigned to variable "User::CUSTOMER_ID" differs from the 
current variable type. Variables may not change type during execution. Variable types 
are strict, except for variables of type Object.
The type of the value being assigned to variable "User::INCIDENT_ID" differs from 
the current variable type. Variables may not change type during execution. Variable 
types are strict, except for variables of type Object.
```

I tried `isnull()` to both columns but of no use, i googled alot but didnt overcome it.

Please help.

Comment: What is the datatype for your variables in SSIS? Is it same as the type of your db columns?

Answer (score 0):

SSIS is unbeleivably fussy in this area.

When retrieving those columns, I would cast them as text e.g. NVARCHAR ( 50 ).  Then the Variables used in the For Each Loop Container can use Data Type = String.